# Mini Game Platform for PC - similar to Warcraft III Custom Games

Tags: networking

I think it would be fun to make a game for pc that has an online community like warcraft, aka there's lobbies and chat rooms and users can host games to play with eachother. And there's no seriousness, just fun mini games that last on average 30-60 minutes, more or less depending on the game.

I searched google but it's really hard to find anything, I don't know the right keywords, I guess. Is there anything similar to this idea that's already out there? Or is this a first?

Also, in making this, any recommendations, flaming, or random comments? (yes I know it is hard to make an online game and such, especially since I have no experience with networking. I do have 2-3 years of programming experience, however).

EDIT:

Some more info on what I want to create. I want it to be easy for users to create games and play with friends. All of us game creators have ideas, and we probably draw them out on paper (graph paper for me). Wouldn't it be amazing if it was a matter of a couple hours to transfer that idea to a fully working game, even if it is in 3d?

Answer (score 0):

i like your idea, i have always wanted to join a team of game developers, count me in.

build a team i'll help you out as much as my posibilities (i think that's how is writen), allow me to

retaking you point, haven't you search in the linux comunnity, we are all glad to join in ambitious projects